# Python not all lines are aligned when writing in a text file

Tags: python, format, text-alignment

I am writing in a text file a list of students aligned by longest (surname +' '+name).
A row in the file should be like this: '{stud_surname} {stud_name}.....\t{stud_grade}\n'
-> where ..... is the difference between the length of longest combination of (surname+' '+name) and the current one <-
The problem is that while some rows of the file are aligned, others are not. I've noticed,by opening the textfile, that if I add a tab in the wrong ones, they become aligned. I am wondering how it is possible since for some words works.
This is the code:

```
top_stud = [el for el in top_stud if el["grade"] >= 28]
top_stud = sorted(top_stud,key = lambda st:(st["stud_surname"],st["stud_name"]))
top_stud = sorted(top_stud,key=lambda st:st["grade"], reverse=True)
ls = max([el["stud_surname"] for el in top_stud],key=len)
ln = max([el["stud_name"] for el in top_stud],key=len)
rows = 0
with open(fileout,'w') as flout:
    for el in top_stud:
            diff = len(ls+' '+ln)-(len(el["stud_surname"])+1+len(el["stud_name"]))
                flout.write("{0} {1:<{x}}\t{2}\n".format(el["stud_surname"],el["stud_name"],el["grade"],x=diff))
                rows += 1
return rows
```

Comment: you should at least provide some data as demo.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try to check the values that are being written to the file? Do they, perhaps, contain unexpected spaces? Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre]. Also, what does this question have to do with JSON?

Comment: Unfortunately tabs do not line up the whole file into a series of columns, one column per value. They usually align with 8-space or 4-space columns, and if a value extends into multiple columns, a tab after it will jump to the next column to the right. This means different length values can lead to misalignment.  Also, the alignment can depend on the program or terminal displaying it. If you really want to align things in columns, you shouldn't use tabs.